# How to store character output from a loop and write as a text file in R?

Tags: r

We can work with data matrix very easily in R, but here I have character strings printed out from my loop as below:

```
for (i in 1:length(mylength)){
DO something to get my_string until length(mylength)
cat(my_string)
collection <-  ##how can I save the my_string one after another leaving one line gap so I can write everything (collection) using the code below?
}
```

How can I save the my_string one after another leaving one line gap so I can write everything (`collection`) using the code below?

```
##writing the collected file
cat(collection, file= "All_colected_mystring.txt")
```

Comment: You can use iteration functions from `purrr` instead, e.g. `map_chr` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0()` to concatenate each piece of the `mylength` string, separated by new lines:

```
collection <- ""

for (i in 1:length(mylength)) {
    # get my_string
    collection <- paste0(collection, "\n")
}

cat(collection)
```

Note that `print()` won't show those newlines, but `cat` should.